# Control the level of detail in a pivot in R (tidyverse)

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot, tidyverse

I have an extremely wide dataset that I am trying to unpivot to a degree but not completely. Essentially I am trying to group certain columns together based on a string before an underscore and pivot on those groups individually. My current method uses two opposite pivots, a for loop, and an intermediate list to accomplish my goal. I am able to get my final product but for my own knowledge, I am wondering if there is a more elegant solution. I realize that I am likely not explaining things well so I have recreated the scenario with a dummy dataset.

```
#Required packages
library(tidyverse)

#Dummy data
file <- as_tibble(data.frame(id = c("QQQ", "WWW", "EEE", "RRR", "TTT"),
                                  state = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee"),
                                  city = c("ff", "gg", "hh", "ii", "jj"),
                       a_1 = runif(5),
                       a_2 = runif(5),
                       a_3 = runif(5),
                       a_4 = runif(5),
                       a_5 = runif(5),
                       a_6 = runif(5),
                       a_7 = runif(5),
                       a_8 = runif(5),
                       a_9 = runif(5),
                       a_10 = runif(5),
                       b_1 = runif(5),
                       b_2 = runif(5),
                       b_3 = runif(5),
                       b_4 = runif(5),
                       b_5 = runif(5),
                       b_6 = runif(5),
                       b_7 = runif(5),
                       b_8 = runif(5),
                       b_9 = runif(5),
                       b_10 = runif(5),
                       c_1 = runif(5),
                       c_2 = runif(5),
                       c_3 = runif(5),
                       c_4 = runif(5),
                       c_5 = runif(5),
                       c_6 = runif(5),
                       c_7 = runif(5),
                       c_8 = runif(5),
                       c_9 = runif(5),
                       c_10 = runif(5)))

#My solution
longer <- file %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(-id:-city),
             names_to = c(".value", "section"),
             names_pattern = "(.+)_([0-9]+$)"
) 


num_letterGroup <- ncol(longer) - 4 #4 is the number of columns i want to retain
wide_list <- vector(mode = "list", length = num_letterGroup)
name_list <- vector(mode = "character", length = num_letterGroup)

for (i in 1:num_letterGroup) {
  col_num <- 4 + i
  col_name <- colnames(longer)[col_num]
  wide <- longer %>%
    select(1:4, all_of(col_name)) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = section, values_from = col_name) %>%
    mutate(letterGroup = col_name)
  wide_list[[i]] <- wide
  name_list[i] <- col_name
}

names(wide_list) <- name_list

wide_df <- bind_rows(wide_list)
```

I realize that the amount of data given might seem excessive but I needed the column numbers to be sequential as well as reach double digits. Thank you in advance for any assistance you can provide.

EDIT TO CLARIFY: wide_df is the final product that I want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

This is actually much simpler than the original answer. (Thanks to @thelatemail)

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(file, 
             cols = -c(id:city), 
             names_to = c('letterGroup', '.value'), 
             names_sep = '_')


# A tibble: 15 x 14
#   id    state city  letterGroup   `1`     `2`    `3`    `4`    `5`    `6`   `7`      `8`    `9`  `10`
#   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>       <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 QQQ   aa    ff    a           0.894 0.534   0.583  0.327  0.497  0.254  0.877 0.236    0.585  0.436
# 2 QQQ   aa    ff    b           0.861 0.897   0.244  0.292  0.818  0.428  0.732 0.322    0.702  0.158
# 3 QQQ   aa    ff    c           0.371 0.842   0.918  0.615  0.346  0.675  0.821 0.718    0.461  0.374
# 4 WWW   bb    gg    a           0.573 0.00886 0.555  0.810  0.480  0.763  0.624 0.0667   0.705  0.872
# 5 WWW   bb    gg    b           0.994 0.652   0.961  0.825  0.398  0.0138 0.560 0.695    0.0171 0.704
# 6 WWW   bb    gg    c           0.113 0.988   0.663  0.0461 0.335  0.478  0.291 0.338    0.386  0.183
# 7 EEE   cc    hh    a           0.482 0.197   0.630  0.442  0.633  0.932  0.317 0.119    0.872  0.678
# 8 EEE   cc    hh    b           0.834 0.378   0.504  0.911  0.644  0.976  0.777 0.485    0.470  0.560
# 9 EEE   cc    hh    c           0.819 0.240   0.683  0.570  0.969  0.956  0.745 0.790    0.0548 0.314
#10 RRR   dd    ii    a           0.887 0.818   0.0266 0.444  0.554  0.817  0.332 0.0801   0.966  0.252
#11 RRR   dd    ii    b           0.416 0.211   0.931  0.105  0.948  0.555  0.201 0.656    0.794  0.526
#12 RRR   dd    ii    c           0.652 0.897   0.741  0.254  0.815  0.154  0.422 0.361    0.925  0.696
#13 TTT   ee    jj    a           0.391 0.626   0.358  0.296  0.804  0.743  0.655 0.000308 0.257  0.415
#14 TTT   ee    jj    b           0.764 0.686   0.0174 0.460  0.0164 0.0718 0.700 0.558    0.341  0.411
#15 TTT   ee    jj    c           0.812 0.995   0.845  0.513  0.987  0.249  0.429 0.749    0.557  0.369
```

---

**Original  Answer**

You can get data completely in long format (no need for intermediate columns), separate the column names in two different columns and get the data in wide format.

```
file %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(id:city)) %>%
  separate(name, into = c('letterGroup', 'col'), sep = "_") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = col, values_from = value)
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to direct `pivot_longer` to break it so that it is in group_value order directly?

Comment: You are right, let me update.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
library(tidyr)
df1 <- pivot_longer(file,cols = names(file)[-c(1:3)]) %>%
  separate(name,into = c('letter','number'),sep = '_') %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = number,values_from = value,id_cols = c() )
#Reshape
df2 <- reshape(as.data.frame(df1),idvar = c('id','state','city','letter'),timevar = 'number',direction = 'wide')
names(df2) <- gsub('value.','',names(df2))
```